# Core Data fetchedProperty issue on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

it has been few days that I am struggling with core Data. My application works very well on iOS 6, when I use iOS 7 on the Simulator I got this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
    reason: '*** -constantValue only defined for abstract class. 
    Define -[NSKeyPathExpression constantValue]!'
```

I use fetchedproperties (n2) in my DataModel and I retriev them as :

```
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",
    [(_maqam.n2)[0] valueForKey:@"noteImgPath"]]];
[B2 setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Which part of the code crashes exactly? Could you print the result of `_maqam.n2`? This exception is associated with class clusters, when a message is passed to an object of subclass of an abstract class, but has not implemented that selector.

Comment: Dear Leo, The origin  of the crash is the retrieving of the fetchedproperty (n2) which is given via a predicate expression in IB (noteID= $FETCH_SOURCE.maqamStartingNote + $FETCH_SOURCE.maqamD1.d1) this retrieving works on iOS 6 but crash on iOS 7 on siulator.